# Excel - Best way to programmatically insert cell data

Tags: microsoft-excel

My spreadsheet has the following format:

```
(empty)
(empty)
(empty)
(empty)
(empty)
(data)
(empty)
(empty)
(data)
(empty)
(empty)
(empty)
(data)
```

What is the best way to insert data into the empty cells from the data immediately below it?

For Example:

```
(empty)
(empty)
(empty)
(empty)
(data1)
(empty)
(empty)
(data2)
```

Becomes:

```
(data1)
(data1)
(data1)
(data1)
(data1)
(data2)
(data2)
(data2)
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your data is in column A, and column B is empty, you can fill column B with this formula:

(Row number 1 here corresponds to the row of the cell in which you are placing this formula.)

`=IF(A1="",B2,A1)`

What this does is look at the cell in the current row. If that value is blank, pull the data from the cell below. The cell below, using the same lookup, will be filled with something which will then trickle up the column to all cells.

After filling in your column B with this, you can copy/paste values into the original fields in column A.

Answer (score 0):

Fill up from the bottom, for example column **D**:

```
Sub FillUp()
    Dim N As Long, L As Long
    N = Cells(Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row
    For L = N - 1 To 1 Step -1
        If Cells(L, "D").Value = "" Then
            Cells(L, "D").Value = Cells(L + 1, "D").Value
        End If
    Next L
End Sub
```

Comment: That's correct. As a side note: Replace `.end(xlUp).ROw` [with a safe method](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14390619/935614)

Comment: @nixda : Thanks!  I'll save your suggestion for my personal toolbox.